# How to install snappy packages in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, 16.04

There are lots of news going on about support for 'Snaps' in 16.04. In the [original post](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/13/snaps-for-classic-ubuntu/), Olli wrote:

> In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS we will make it possible to install snap packages
>   alongside traditional deb packages. These two packaging formats live
>   quite comfortably next to one another and enable us to maintain our
>   existing processes for development and updates to the OS

and he goes on talking about developers and security..etc..

But questions remain as to how to find a snappy package and how to install a snappy package? How to even know if an application has a snappy package? Is there a 'snappy repository' that hosts these snappy applications?

Comment: This thread [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760167/how-to-use-snaps-in-16-04) was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to first:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-snappy-cli
```

then you search the repo by:

```
sudo snap find
```

but by now the repo is small

to install nmap for example:

```
sudo snap install nmap
```

to show all the installed snaps:

```
sudo snap list
```

that is it.

Now, the dpkg system will show blank entry, as a proof that nmap is not installed via DPKG:

```
dpkg -l |grep nmap
```

the nmap snap binary is installed under:

```
:~$ which nmap
/snap/bin/nmap
```

To update a snap:

```
sudo snap refresh nmap
```

But I still have to find out why the sudo command wouldn't find the binary of the snap package:

```
:~$ sudo nmap
sudo: nmap: command not found
```

Comment: Thank you. I had already tried this, but I need more info, especially about the existence of 'snap repository'.

Comment: libsnappy-dev is correct

Answer (score 3):

My error info:

```
note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsnappy
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and I install:

```
sudo apt install libsnappy-dev
```

and solved the error.